# Swift - UISlider doesn't change its value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I programmatically created an UISlider and I created an action that runs evertime I change the slider value. The actions print out the slider.value. The problem is that the value printed out is always 0. Even if I move the slider.
This is the code:

```
import UIKit

class EditVC: UIViewController {

var slider : UISlider {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 85, width: editView.frame.width - 30, height: 20)
    let slider = UISlider(frame: frame)
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.maximumValue = 10
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChangedFunc), for: .valueChanged)

    return slider

    }

@objc func valueChangedFunc() {
    print(slider.value)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(slider)   
}
}
```

Comment: Is that code right? You have a variable called `sliderI` but then later on you reference just `slider`

Comment: It was just a typo when I was writing the question. Now it's fine, thank you

Comment: You've created a read-only computed property for `slider` that returns a new instance of `UISlider` everytime it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code, I have tested it and it is working fine

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    createMPSlider()
}

func createMPSlider()
{
    let mSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.55, height: 60))
    mSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChangedOfSlider(slider:)), for: .valueChanged)
    view .addSubview(mSlider)
}

func valueChangedOfSlider(slider: UISlider)
{
    print(slider.value)
}
```

This above code is working fine. What you need to do is to copy createMPSlider() & valueChangedOfSlider(slider: UISlider) these two complete functions and paste it on your view controller and call createMPSlider() from viewDidLoad it will work.
If you want you can declare  at the top if you want to change customize slider or use it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

I moved some code and removed the @objc in your function.

```
 import UIKit

class EditVC: UIViewController {

func addSlider() -> UISlider {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 85, width: editView.frame.width - 30, height: 20)
        let slider = UISlider(frame: frame)
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = 10
        slider.isContinuous = true
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChangedFunc), for: .valueChanged)

    return slider

    }

func valueChangedFunc() {
    print(slider.value)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(addSlider())   
}
}
```